# Error uploading large binaries into SDL Tridion Multimedia Components

Tags: tridion

I am using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, and uploading large binaries as Multimedia Components. This works fine for binaries up to about 30Mb, after that the CME fails to upload files. I assume this is some sort of web.config setting to limit binary sizes, does anyone know which config files I need to change to allow binaries of up to 100Mb. Are these CMS specific settings, and will I need to make additional changes to support uploading these large files over WebDAV?

I am fully aware that I could use "External Multimedia Components" for this, but we have a few large binaries that we want to use full version control on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the answer of your question; you are almost on the way.

First thing what we need to understand is by default Tridion WebUI will not set any maxFilesize in web.config so, Tridion CME will take machine config file size [it is by default 30MB].

Here to upload bigger file you need to add following node under webUI webconfig which will located at c:\programfiles(x86)\Tridion\web\WebUi\WebRoot\

```html
<security>
   <requestFiltering>
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/>
   </requestFiltering>
 </security>
```

Please make sure maxAllowedContentLength only accept in byte....

for e.g. you need to go for maxAllowedContentLength to 1GB then it should be like 10240000000

I hope this answer will solved your problem ...
All the best,

regards,
Hiren

Comment: I also had to add <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1073741824"/> into the config under the <system.web> as well.

Answer (score 7):

Try these link from the SDL Tridion Documentation Portal (requires login)

For WebDAV: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_E1E4BB75BEB84404B4EFAFC6B8A22D15

For the CME: http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/CME_concept_242A17EC385644C8A77F2C976576492C

Comment: Is that just for WebDAV? I have made those changes, but still have problems when uploading through the CME

Comment: no its not just for WebDAV, see [this topic](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/CME_concept_242A17EC385644C8A77F2C976576492C) which explains the same settings for the issue you encounter

Comment: I'm having an issue uploading a PDF that's 47MB large. When I follow the above steps, it works fine when uploading the file on the CM server. But when I upload the file via a client CME, I would get to about 60%, resend for upload and then error out with the following message in the GUI "Unable to recongize the upload state data". Any ideas here?