# Error uploading the large size multimedia component in tridion

Tags: tridion

I am trying to upload the video (.flv) file of 400 Mb in tridion but getting error "unable to recognize the upload state data"

I tried adding below code

```
<security> 
   <requestFiltering> 
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/> 
   </requestFiltering> 
 </security>
```

in the web.config present on the path
\Tridion\web

Am I updating on wrong path?
Please suggest?

Thanks
Meenakshi

Comment: do smaller files work correctly, if so to what size can you roughly upload? also have you checked out the IIS and Tridion logs for more detail?

Comment: Did you restart SDL Tridion website in IIS?

Have you also checked that the multimedia schema you are using can accept flv files or the flv isn't corrupt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error uploading large binaries into SDL Tridion Multimedia Components](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779054/error-uploading-large-binaries-into-sdl-tridion-multimedia-components)

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a duplicate of [Error uploading large binaries into SDL Tridion Multimedia Components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779054/error-uploading-large-binaries-into-sdl-tridion-multimedia-components)

Did you read that answer it describes changing these settings in c:\programfiles(x86)\Tridion\web\WebUi\WebRoot\web.config

Answer (score 0):

In System.Web section add the tag

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1073741824"/>
```

Hope this will resolve your issue.